# Error configure service fabric api with api management

Tags: api, azure-service-fabric, azure-api-management, subnet, vnet

I am trying to configure Api hosted in service fabric cluster with API management gateway using ARM template. I am getting below error:

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 9:08:39 PM - Resource Microsoft.ApiManagement/service 'RCISAPIGateway' failed with message

```
{
  "code": "UpdateApiServiceFailed",
  "message": "Subnet Subnet-0 is in use by /subscriptions/d1b97a81-6cd1-4929-bd0b-afc8eedb8ee7/resourceGroups/RCIS_ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/|providers|Microsoft.Compute|virtualMachineScaleSets|nod06rcis|virtualMachines|0|networkInterfaces|NIC-comsvfab06rciscimax-0/ipConfigurations/NIC-comsvfab06rciscimax-0 and cannot be updated with resource navigation links for external resources.",
  "details": null,
  "innerError": null
}
```

My question are:

1. How can I resolve this issue?
2. Is there any way I can configure API management for Service Fabric from Azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to add two different resources into same VNET subnet in Azure. 
Try adding a separate subnet for APIM service.